# Adding jQuery to sublime text 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, sublimetext2

I am new to jQuery world, and only today started using sublime text 2. Therefore, I am not aware of what packages I have to download and how to download. So, I would kindly request if anyone know how do I add jQuery to use it in my sublime text 2 editor. It will be great if you can give me a step by step instructions, like I said I am new to this. Also, how to get list of selections for jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciate it. Thanks :]

Comment: you don't have to add jquery to sublime, you just have to include it in your page ie: `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>`. Before even adding packages to Sublime, it is recommended to use [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)

Comment: @alme1304 u sure? because it doesnt work. I did have a link

Comment: Easy like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcAN4D1QV6o

Comment: positive. How do you know it does not work?

Comment: @alme1304 because I have made a jQuery within sublime and try to run it but it doesnt work

Comment: @roXon and how does this video suppose to answer my question? Totally different issue.

Comment: Now after your comment I can just ask my self *what is actually your question* ? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @roXon I would like to be able to use jQuery in sublimetext2. The video doesn't tell you anything about jQuery. Correct me if I am wrong, but like i've mentioned I am a beginner to this.

Comment: jquery is just a javascript file. Any editor can use it out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a JS library. To use it you need to include it in your document like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Than you'll be able to manipulate your DOM elements/events doing crazy stuff like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('body').prepend('HELLO EVERYONE!');
    });
</script>
```

or like

### [this demo](http://jsbin.com/aqopur/1/edit)

To help you in your work Sublime has a possibility to easily include that jQuery library by creating a *shortcut snippet*, I'll show you how:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>New Snippet...</kbd>

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>jquery</tabTrigger> <!-- the text that using [Tab] will paste the snippet -->
</snippet>
```

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Save As...</kbd>
(Under *Documents And Settings/yourUserName/Application Data/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/* )

`jquery.sublime-snippet`

Restart Sublime type `jquery` + hit your <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and the jQuery library **snippet** will be included in your document.

The same way you can create your own snippets that you use over and over for example like

```
$(function(){

});
```

```
var intv = setInterval(function(){

}, 1000 );
```

Comment: Can you please explain this snippet bussiness? Like I said, I am a beginner I have no knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Although, I have found  video which shows me how to download the jQuery bundle. I don't know if I was clear or not. But for the effort in explaining, thumbs up :)

Comment: I would like to keep the files seperate. So if i create a jQuery file, and link it to html file. What do I have to add inside the jQuery file?

Comment: @user123 You see the demo jsBin I added into my answer? Click on the JsBin logo and click "Download". After you download the .html file you'll see how it all works. The jQuery library is included from Google APIs, than if you want to have a separate file for your functions, create a functions.js file and link to it. In that JS file all you need to do is to wrap your code into *DOM ready function*.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text 2 is just an editor, you don't need to use the packages, snippets, etc. to use jQuery. In the HTML file where you want to use jQuery, you need to add a script tag that points to where the jQuery framework lives (this can either be a local path to where you placed jQuery, or a url of where jQuery resides on the internet).

For example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        // your code goes here, you can use jQuery at this point
    });
</script>
```

As for a list of "selections" that really depends on the HTML markup you use. At this point, I can only recommend you read the jQuery documentation. Here's a link to their learning center: http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: I would like to keep the files seperate. So if i create a jQuery file, and link it to html file. What do I have to add inside the jQuery file?