# Jquery not loading local html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have looked around but still can't get my code to load my html file. From my index.html file I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>David Anderson, Georgia Tech Professor</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/body.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/footer.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#header').load('header.html');
            alert("Does this load!!!??")
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <div id="header"></div>

        <section class="section_2 index_section">
        ...
        </section>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

And such.
I included the alert for debugging purposes and it works fine, but it never loads my header.html file. I have included both files in the same directory and level.

My header.html includes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/body.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/Stylesheets/footer.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <!------------
    -   Header   -
    ------------->

    <header class="section_1" id="header">
        <img src="Images/David's_typical_Profile_Picture.jpg" alt="David Anderson" id="prof_pic">
        
        <h1 id="name_plate">
            <a class="name_plate" href="about.html">David Anderson</a>
        </h1>

        <h2 id="institution_name">
            Georgia Institute of Technology
        </h2>

        <nav id="main_nav">
            <ul class="semantic_list">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://anderson.ece.gatech.edu/ece6254/index.html" target="_blank">ECE 6254</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://anderson.ece.gatech.edu/ece6271/index.html" target="_blank">ECE 6271</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="lab.html">Lab</a></li>
                <li><a href="consulting.html">Consulting</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header> 
</html>
```

I have looked around everywhere, including [Adding jQuery to sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260945/adding-jquery-to-sublime-text-2), [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ as well as websites about writing/including javascript: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/multiple-pages-without-repeating-the-site-structure/8251/3, https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/calling-multiple-htmls-into-single-html-file/216583/2, but I still run into the same problem, where it simply doesn't load header.html. Ever.

I am loading it on safari using a local path, not a website.
If anyone has a solution/or answer I'd be very grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.